# Stopping a key event from firing excessively

Tags: javascript

I made a simple image gallery with a lightbox-style modal each time the image clicks.  (I called it lightbox, but it's not the Lightbox library.)  It works and I started getting creative with it, deciding to make the images navigable if I hit the arrow keys while the modal is open.

This *almost* works.  The images usually go back in forth in order.  However, sometimes it'll flash to the wrong image before it goes to the right one.  I've captured it doing this by using `console.log` on the index of the array that holds the images.  What I see in my console is a bunch of weird numbers between the consecutive numbers.  It'll go from the right image, to the right image, but occasionally it'll flicker.  It seems to often report those weird numbers, whether it flickers or not.  It doesn't always do this, so I'm not entirely sure what the cause is, but I suspect that it's reading "key_up" too many times.

Here's the code:

```
//Allow for keyboard navigation, only if the lightbox is open.
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event)=> {
    if(lightbox) {
        if(event.key === "ArrowRight") {
            index++;
            if(index === images.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            lb_img.firstElementChild.src = images[index].src;
            console.log(index);
        }

        if(event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
            index--;
            if(index === -1) {
                index = images.length - 1;
            }
            lb_img.firstElementChild.src = images[index].src;
            console.log(index);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want the full code, I have it on a gist:  https://gist.github.com/jckuhl/f8a56349d29308eb4af207a09787270a

EDIT:  gist is updated with the new code.

And here's an example of my console:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/augDo.jpg

Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Comment: if you think an event is being fired more than it should you might want to search/learn about debounce; here's a good introduction: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: You are adding the keyup listener inside your click listener. Which each click on an image, an additional listener is added to `document`, causing the above code to run multiple times on each `keyup` event. You need to move the adding of the listener outside the image loop.

Comment: @ChrisG That did it.  My original line of thought was that I only needed the images to be navigable while the modal was open, so I added the event listener inside my "click" event listener.  Which had the unintended consequence of adding new "key up" event listeners each time I clicked on an image.

A bit of refactoring and it seems to be working now.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanKuhl Did you just explain to me the very thing I explained to you 10 minutes ago...?

Comment: @ChrisG. No.  Just affirming that what you explained to me worked.

Comment: @JonathanKuhl That's what the first three words did. The rest, apart from not making sense, is my explanation repeated back at me. Oh well, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the eventlistener as much times as you have clicked on images, because you attach it inside the eventhandler for the click event. This is causing your trouble.

Make sure you attach it only once, by initializing it outside the for loop and outside the click handler.